# create new language project item in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2005, projects-and-solutions

I have created a custom template using vsz and vsdir files and can make it appear under visual studio 2005 New Project' Visual C# or Visual C++. But since the template is used to create a makefile type of project so I can use my own build system, I need it in a new folder like Visual C# or Visual C++. Does anyone know what I should do for this to happen? And I know this is possible since our company uses Intel Fortran for visual studio which has Intel Fortran in the New Project types together with Visual C#, other languages and Other Project Types.

Thank you in advance.